# Function wrapper/decorator in OCaml

Tags: function, ocaml, wrapper

I have a function with the following signature:

```
val func : a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f -> unit
```

and sometimes it raises exceptions. I want to change the control flow so that it looks like this:

```
val funcw : a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f -> [ `Error of string | `Ok of unit ]
```

The way I tried wrapping it is ugly: make another function, `funcw`, that takes the same amount of arguments, applies `func` to them, and does `try`/`with`. But there must be a better way than that. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `f` a parameter of the wrapper function. That's a little more general.

```
let w6 f a b c d e g =
    try `Ok (f a b c d e g) with e -> `Error (Printexc.to_string e)
```

A wrapped version of `func` is then `(w6 func)`

This wrapper works for curried functions of 6 arguments, like your `func`. You can't really define a single wrapper for all the different numbers of arguments (as they have different types), but you can define a family of wrappers for different numbers of arguments like this:

```
let w1 f x = try `Ok (f x) with e -> `Error (Printexc.to_string e)
let ws f x y =
    match f x with
    | `Ok f' -> (try `Ok (f' y) with e -> `Error (Printexc.to_string e))
    | `Error _ as err -> err
let w2 f = ws (w1 f)
let w3 f x = ws (w2 f x)
let w4 f x y = ws (w3 f x y)
let w5 f x y z = ws (w4 f x y z)
let w6 f x y z w = ws (w5 f x y z w)
```

There might be a tidier scheme but this seems pretty good.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I had 2 `f`s (one a function and one a type). Changed to `func` and `funcw`. I'd rather avoid this kind of solution, since it removes the single point of truth for which arguments `func` takes.

Comment: FWIW types and values occupy different namespaces. You can have a function named f and a type named f.

Comment: I ended up coming up with an applicative functor shim into the library we were using. See https://github.com/facebook/reason/pull/995/files#diff-4af8301f4de922b46619ac3c3932dbeb if curious. Thank you for your help!